# What is the difference between string::at and string[i]? (C++)

Tags: c++, string, indexing

In C++, what is the difference between the `string.at(i)` method and `string[i]`? What are the advantages or disadvantages to using one or the other?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
   std::string s = "Hello World";
   std::cout << s.at(1) << endl;
   std::cout << s[1] << endl;
}
```

As far as I know, they do the same thing, but I don't know much about C++.

Comment: `std::string::at` throws if the index you pass is out of range (i.e. if it's `>= s.size()`); `std::string::operator[]` does not.

Answer (score 3):

[`std::string.at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/at) member function accesses the specified character **with bounds checking** while the [`std::string::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at) accesses the specified character **without bounds checking**.

That is, with `std::string::at`, bounds checking is performed and exception of type `std::out_of_range` will be thrown on invalid access.

On the other hand, with `std::string::operator[]`, no bounds checking is performed. If `pos > size()`, the behavior is **undefined**.

Answer (score 0):

`s.at()` raises an `out_of_range` exception if we try to access a position which is out of allocated limits.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s = "ABCD";
    // cout << s[100] << endl; // No Exception Raised
    cout << s.at(100) << endl;  // Raises An Exception

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Images can't be copied, tested, compiled or googled

Comment: Best not to show code snippets as graphics.

Comment: Added the code too, i thought it would be better if i can show the output too :)

Comment: The output is text

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/995714)